# missing payoffs.hpp and other .hpp from version

Tags: windows, quantlib

When building the Windows C++ version of `quantlib` 1.9.1, I get this error of missing `payoffs.hpp`. When I browse to the directories, I see `payoffs.cpp`, but not `payoffs.hpp`:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'ql/instruments/payoffs.hpp': No such file or directory   FittedBondCurve c:\users\administrator\google drive\quantlib-1.9.1\ql\cashflows\conundrumpricer.hpp 27
```

I also get this for `#include <ql/instruments/swap.hpp>` [and possibly others]. I am able to build the windows quantlib library ok. Just not the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the QuantLib 1.9.1 release available from the [project downloads](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/files/QuantLib/1.9.1/) (did you get your version from there?) and the files you're looking for are contained in the release zip and tarball.  Also, it's pretty weird that you could compile the library without them, so I'd double check if they're there.  If they really aren't—well, hard to know how they got displaced; anyway, you can download the release again and replace them. If that doesn't fix the problem (or if they're already there after all), it's possible that you have to fix the include path for the example you're trying to compile. Does it include the QuantLib directory?